# How to improve Hibernate performance in Java?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have thousands of records which need to be retrieved on a single user click. Currently it is giving me the results very slowly, I have to wait for a long time. Is there a way to improve retrieving these results using hibernate?

I have a case where a method which has a select query will run every single minute. This is where Hibernate is giving me the slow result. I am using Hibernate with MySQL.

Comment: That's a bit like saying "How long is a piece of string?".  We need more detail about what your HQL is.  Just a simple "where" clause could dramatically speed things up.

Comment: Are you using any caching? (hibernate.cache.user_query_cache = true)

Comment: Retrieving lots of data from a database is just slow, Hibernate or not. Reduce the number of rows that you are retrieving, for example, by presenting them a few hundred rows at a time. Your users cannot look at all 10000 rows at the same time anyway, so there is no point of presenting them with that much information.

Comment: Retrieving 10000 rows can be faster than retrieving 1. But it all depends on how the rows are retrieved, and on the indexes in the database. Without any information, it's impossible to help.

Comment: I have a case where a method which has select query will run every single minute. This is where hibernate giving me slow result

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Common practice is enabling of 2nd level cache and query cache. Than your data will be readed from memmory not from db.

Good article about it [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html)

Other things can be helpfull:

1 Indexing - in case there is where and ordering - you have to build indexes for fields you are searching/ordering - this can improve search speed up 10 times

2 Denormalisation - if you have a lot of joins some denormalisation (putting all in single table) can help. But this should be final solution when everything else fails.

Comment: I have a case where a method which has select query will run every single minute. This is where hibernate giving me slow result

Comment: With 2nd level cache and query cache enabled it will populate entities after first execution of query. So first time can take slow. But next times it will use cached values. Reading from memory will be faster

Comment: i have denormilezed some tables, apply all the available cache posible, added a connection pool but still it took ages for hiberante to return some queries, it seems to me that the qquery excetution in the data base is not the problem, but once the resultset is returned and hibernate translate that to beans, is there any way to improve that parsin?

Comment: The query can be executed fast, but the issue might be not in hibernate mapping of records to bean but in records reading via network from DB. ?
You can check it executing same query and fetch all results without hibernate with plain JDBC. If it takes same time - then that's not a hibernate issue.
For huge results think do you really need to query and return 1000 records? Probably not - you can do it with pagination, for example.
If it is hibernate issue, well, then probably worth do not use hibernate.

Comment: Personally I am try to avoid hibernate usage in my new projects. Last my opinion is that I am spending more time trying to hack hibernate to make it work as I expect it to work.And that time is greater than I am saving using relation mapping

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you go for `Pagination` if you have to display the records on a web page and retrieve part of the records at one time say 100.